# Can a contract reveal hidden info only when someone pays it?

Tags: contract-development

Can anyone think of a way to store hidden information on a contract and then reveal it only when the contract receives payment?

I'm pretty stumped. Im guessing its impossible?

But if there were a solution, could it involve encryption and oracles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have an external service that checks if someone paid, and give access to that person to the `secret information`.

This is somehow the opposite of what oracle is. Oracle `gives` information about the world for smart-contracts (DApps) to use (execute payouts and whatnot). In your case it's just app that uses the blockchain data (info about transactions).

If you need this information in the blockchain I can think of a way, but it will be more costly:

The external service (as in the example above) checks of someone paid for a resource, then adds the `hidden information` encrypted with the public key of the `payer`. Payer can decrypt it with his hidden key now.

This will be expensive because storing data in the blockchain costs more gas (the more data, the more gas). And on top - you would need to repeat it for every payer, so it means duplication.

You could work around it, by publishing an encryption key (encrypted by payer's public key again) of the encrypted, publicly available `secret information` if it's big. You would need to maintain it on some server though.

In any case - your `secret information` remains secret until one of the payers decide to publish it somewhere in an unencrypted form.

Comment: Could i use an oracle as the external service? This way I can have the logic of purchasing the key on the contract as well. So basically the oracle could sell the key?

Comment: Oracle is a service that looks at the outside world for events and writes to blockchain (e.g. triggers payment). What you need is a service that looks at blockchain, and write to blockchain. So it's not strictly an oracle. Your problem is much simpler and don't involve all the problems related to oracles.

Comment: Is there a way to decentralize the process of checking to see if someone paid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `decentralization` in this context. I'm guessing that you want to release the `secret information` into the wild, and expect only some to have access to it. Like DRM, but on blockchain - am I guessing right? If yes - I can't think of any technology, blockchain itself will not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store hidden information within a contract.

Even if a contract source has not been publically released, once the contract is uploaded, it is readable and has to be verified by everyone on the network.

Linking to an Oracle is an option to an extent.

Comment: It's true that everything on the blockchain is visible, but it does not have to be readable. The same way everything on the IP network is visible, but your communication with bank remains private (ssl, https)

Comment: @meta What I meant by `readable`, I was referring more or less to how computer permissions works (aka. `chmod`)